# Get string values from array in object that is in an array

Tags: javascript, json, mapping

I have the following JSON object:

```js
var test = {
  data: [{
      itemID: 0,
      categories: [{
        id: 0,
        type: 'a',
        name: 'world'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        type: 'b',
        name: 'plants'
      }]
    },
    {
      itemID: 1,
      categories: [{
        id: 2,
        type: 'w',
        name: 'cars'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        type: 't',
        name: 'bicycles'
      }]
    }

  ]

};
console.log([].concat
.apply([],  test.data.map(item => item.categories.map(el => el.type))));
```

What I want to do is, to get all types in an array.
So the result should look like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'w', 't']
```

What I did:

```
[].concat
.apply([],  test.data.map(item => item.categories.map(el => el.type)))
```

I have the feeling that this could be done easier.

Does someone know a better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var test = {data: [{itemID: 0,categories: [{id: 0,type: 'a',name: 'world'}, {id: 1,type: 'b',name: 'plants'}]},{itemID: 1,categories: [{id: 2,type: 'w',name: 'cars'}, {id: 3,type: 't',name: 'bicycles'}]}]};

let result = test.data.reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c.categories.map(v => v.type)), []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

Where **depth** is *Optional*

> The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.

```js
var test = {
  data: [{
      itemID: 0,
      categories: [{
        id: 0,
        type: 'a',
        name: 'world'
      }, {
        id: 1,
        type: 'b',
        name: 'plants'
      }]
    },
    {
      itemID: 1,
      categories: [{
        id: 2,
        type: 'w',
        name: 'cars'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        type: 't',
        name: 'bicycles'
      }]
    }

  ]

};

var type = test.data.map(item => item.categories.map(el => el.type)).flat();
console.log(type);
```